# How to push update to a flutter app which is not uploaded on play store

Tags: flutter, google-play, updates, auto-update, sideloading

I have a scenario where in i am building an flutter app which i don't want to upload to google play store. I will provide the `.apk` to download via website .

Now i have a new version of the app which i replaced the old `.apk` file with in the website.

Now how to push the notification to the user and ask them to update the latest version of the app.

Should i have to maintain some github repository where i maintain the releases ?
Any suggestion to this complete scenario would be greatly helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- create an api that return latest app version

2- always make a request to this API when ever the user open the app check the API latest version and user app version (I recommend using [package_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/package_info_plus))

3- inform user with the new app if app version != latest version(API)

Answer (score 1):

1. You can user firebase or any notification service to send notification from server to the users you can schedule notification that trigger when update is added in the server
2. you can create the  dialog that check the version of your apk and check through the server api where latest version in updated in api and you can show the dialog every time